# При обрезании строки возвращает undefined

Tags: javascript

Обрезаю строку, нужно, чтоб обрезало на пробеле, но не короче 80 знаков, пробовал через циклы, переводил в массив, все равно undefined.(в строке больше, чем 80 знаков)

```js
let cutStr = (str, num = 80) => {
        if (str[num] === ' ') {
            return str.slice(0, num)
        } else {
            cutStr(str, num+1)
        }
    }
    
    console.log(cutStr(abc))
```

Comment: а где то указано, что должно _возвращать_ иное?

Comment: можно вообще регулярками решить задачу. вроде как нить так https://regex101.com/r/ht6AZQ/2 но выглядит не очень

Comment: а так еще в задаче не мешало бы проверить, что длина исходной строки вообще больше 80. Рекурсия, тут конечно ни к чему, цикла должно быть достаточно, а то на большом тексте можно и выпасть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.match(/.{80,}( |$)/)[0].slice(0, -1)`

Возвратит первую минимум 80-символьную строку, обрезанную до пробела (не включая пробел) или до конца строки (если подходящей подстроки не встретилось)

Answer (score 1):

```
return cutStr(str, num+1)
^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение через регулярку для длины 8.

```js
values = ['qwe', 'qweqweqweqwe asdasdasd', 'qwe qwe qwe aaa'];

let cutStr = s => s.replace(/^(.{8,}?)\s.*/, '$1');


console.log(values.map(cutStr));
```

а так в вашем решении отсутствует `return` и в целом рекурсия на большом тексте приведет к крашу. здесь достаточно цикла. Если строка короче то возвращаете. А так пишите `while(s[++num] != ' ');`  или до конца строки, после чего вовзращаете `slice` до полученного `num`